# Runtime error when deploying on Google App Engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, voila

I am trying to deploy a small dashboard using a jupyter notebook and voila on the Google App Engine.

Once the files have been uploaded to google cloud storage I get the following error:

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
#============================================================#
#= Uploading 4 files to Google Cloud Storage                =#
#============================================================#
File upload done.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error(s) encountered validating runtime. Unknown runtime "python310".
```

I'm assuming this is an error in my app.yaml file as python 3.10 is supported.

This is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python310
env: flex

entrypoint: bash -c "voila --port $PORT --Voila.ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser notebook.ipynb"
```

My notebook was built in an environment using Python 3.10.9

This is my first time trying to deploy on the Google App Engine and I am unsure how to overcome this error.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#newversions) which says

> For Python runtime version 3.8 and later, you must include the **runtime_config** and **operating_system** settings in your app.yaml to specify an operating system.

There are examples on the above link showing you how to specify both settings

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help. If I could follow up with another question. The app gets 'built' but I get this error: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>1: bash: line 1: voila: command not found. But voila==0.4.0 is in my requirements.txt file?

Comment: @eyrie01 Did you import the package/module?